# Add constants to existing ES6 class

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-class

I would like to have a class with some constants, so I can make calls such as:

```js
const MyClass = require('./myclass.js');

console.log(MyClass.CONST1);
console.log(MyClass.CONST2);
let a = new MyClass();
...
```

My problem: I have to define a large amount of constants, so I would like to have a distinct block of code where the constants are defined, apart from my class definition:

1. a stand-alone object which defines the constants
2. the class definition

... And afterwards, merge them together into a single class definition so the caller use the constants as if they were part of the class definition.

Here is the way I found to do so, but I don't know if this is correct or if it could lead to some problems:

myclass.js

```js
const MYCONSTANTS = {
   CONST1: 1,
   CONST2: 2
};

class MyClass {
   constructor() {
   }
}

// "merge" constants into MyClass
let exportedClass = Object.assign(MyClass, MYCONSTANTS);

// freeze exportedClass in order to forbid any change in constants values 
Object.freeze(exportedClass);

// export
module.exports = exportedClass;
```

It seems to work, but I am not sure the way I "extend" the class is correct: I manipulate `MyClass` as if it was a variable (with Object.assign). Maybe there is a better/safer way to achieve this ?

Comment: Variables don't contain objects, only references to objects. What comes to the code, it actually doesn't work as you want it like "_merge [constants] ... as if they were part of the class definition_", instead, the constants are added as a "static" properties to the class, they are not inherited to the instances. Do `MyClass.prototype.constants = {...}` to add the constants to the actual prototype, that way they can be inherited.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu : I understand the difference. But if I only need to use constants as static data (<=> using them as "MyClass.CONST1"), does my way of doing is ok ?

Comment: Althought `class` is a function, `Object.assign` works fine with it, no problems at all. Functions are actually objects (just with internal [[Callable]] flag set), and assigning new properties to functions is OK.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, @Teemu !